# PHP MySQL Insert Form not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database named "culvers" with a user_id INT(4) auto incrementing, a full_name varchar(20) and a user_name varchar(20).  I am trying to use this HTML form to add values to the table, but it is not working. I have explored dozens of tutorials and help sites, and it still isn't working. I even put the code on another hosting provider to see if that was the problem. When I click "add" I am taken to a blank page (which is expected, since I don't have a success/error message) but the form data does not insert into the database table.

Also, I know I should sanitize my inputs, but that's not the issue right now. (At least I don't think so)

Here's the form.html code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Add User to Table</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Add User</h1>
        <form action="adduser.php" method="POST">
            <label>Full name:</label>
            <input id="postname" type="text" name="fullname">
            <label>Username:</label>
            <input id="postuser" type="text" name="username">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's the adduser.php code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $connection =  mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxx", "xxxxxxxxxx");
    mysql_select_db("culvers");
    $fullnameOfUser = $_POST['fullname'];
    $usernameOfUser = $_POST['username'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (full_name, user_name) VALUES ('$fullnameOfUser', '$usernameOfUser');
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $connection);
    mysql_close($connection);
}else{
    echo "Error no form data";
}
?>
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: "Also, I know I should sanitize my inputs, but that's not the issue right now. (At least I don't think so)" -> Basically we're telling you you should stop using `mysql_*` functions, especially if you will build more code above this or if you will release your code to the public. We strongly discourage you from releasing a program using those functions as those are currently deprecated and represent a security issue.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the double quotes !

```
'$fullnameOfUser', '$usernameOfUser')"; 
                                 ----^ // Add one there
```

### The right code.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`full_name`, `user_name`) VALUES ('$fullnameOfUser', '$usernameOfUser')";
```

You need to switch to [`PreparedStatements`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) seriously as the above code of yours is directly prone to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

you have error in this line :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (full_name, user_name) VALUES ('$fullnameOfUser', '$usernameOfUser');
```

you did not have ending `"`

this line should be :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (full_name, user_name) VALUES ('$fullnameOfUser', '$usernameOfUser')";
```

You should use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` since all functions of `mysql_*` are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You miss the double Quotes at the end of SELECT Query

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO users (full_name, user_name) VALUES ('$fullnameOfUser', '$usernameOfUser')";
```

Answer (score 0):

First if it is not a typo the you need to add a double quote to query.

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO users (full_name, user_name) VALUES ('$fullnameOfUser', '$usernameOfUser')";
```

if still issue remains then print query and run it directly in phpmyadmin to see there is not issue with query.

Note: you are using `mysql_*` function. Please used `PDO` or `Mysqli` as your current code is prone to `Sql Injection.`

PDO Link: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

Before submitting your form data, you need to start the mysql server.
you can start mysql server by the use of xampp software. once you have started your mysql server through xampp software, you can find the mysql server port number also.
the actual format of including the database is,

```
mysql_connect("localhost:port/database","username","password");
```